# ¿Cómo puedo abrir un archivo excel, con librerias estandar en python y pasar la información a listas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, estructuras-de-datos

La única información que encontré fue el usar para abrir el archivo que necesito:

' **f = open('COVID19', 'r')
f.readlines()** '

mas de ahí ocupé

```
class Node:
def __init__(self, next=None, prev=None, data=None):
    self.next = next
    self.prev = prev
    self.data = data
```

para generar nodos, pero de ahi no se me ocurre nada para poder meter la información a los nodos y que de estos, al imprimir, salga la información del excel

Comment: Hola Pridesan, te doy la bienvenida a [es.so]. En la biblioteca estándar no hay nada para parsear archivos XLSX/XLS de MS Excel directamente (otra cosa es csv por ejemplo, pero con "archivo excel" supongo que te refieres a .xlsx o el antiguo xls). ¿Se podría implementar? Si, pero es un trabajo considerable. ¿que te impide usar una de la múltiples bibliotecas externas que permiten trabajar con estos archivos?

Comment: Es para una tarea de universidad, pidieron que hicieramos todo bajo librerias estandar, siii, me falto agregar que es csv, fue mala mia ese pequeño gran detalle :(

Comment: A eso es otra cosa... XD Entonces usa el módulo [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html). En la propia documentación tienes varios ejemplo de uso. Si te atascas, agrega el código y muy importante, un fragmento con algunas líneas del csv incluida la primera (cabeceras si las tiene) para poder reproducir el problema.